# The boundary of the countable points $\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{npq}}, \;n=1,2,\dots, \; k=0,1,\dots,n$ is the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I came across this statement while reading the Introduction of Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures.

If $A$ consists of the countably many points 
$$\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{npq}}, \;n=1,2,\dots, \; k=0,1,\dots,n$$ then the boundary of $A$, i.e. $\partial A$ is the entire real line.

How can we prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$. If $n$ is sufficiently large then we have the inequalities

1) $b \leq \frac {n(1-p)} {\sqrt {npq}}$

2) $a \geq -\frac {np} {\sqrt {npq}}$

3) $(b-a) \sqrt {npq} >1$.

Now consider the interval  $(a\sqrt {npq} +np, b\sqrt {npq}+np)$.

Verify that this interval has length exceeding $1$, that the left end point is $\geq 0$ and the right end point is $ \leq n$.

These facts imply that the interval contains an integer $k$ and we necessarily have $0 \leq k \leq n$. Now $\frac {k-np} {\sqrt {npq}} \in (a,b)$

We have proved that the given set intersects every open interval $(a,b)$. Hence its closure is the entire real line. Being countable, it has no interior. It follows that the boundary is the entire real line.